# stop Streaming API twitter

Tags: api, twitter, streaming, disconnect

I'm connecting to twitter streaming api and want to disconnect after certain time, I'm using threading but it doesn't stop, any suggestion:

def call_twitter():

```
t1 = Thread(target=call_stream)
t1.daemon = True
t1.start()
sleep(15)
```

def call_stream():

```
stream = MyStreamer(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
stream.statuses.filter(track=tags, locations=locs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem and eventually, what worked for me was ES6:

```
setTimeout(() => stream.stop(), 5000)
```